# Swift Cocoa manipulate design of titlebar buttons

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, nswindow, titlebar

I'm currently developing a Swift/Cocoa application with XCode 12.3 and Swift 5.

I'd like to manipulate the design of the close button in the titlebar of a NSWindow.

I've already tried to change the design using

```
self.window?.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.layer. ... = ...
```

But this approach seems not to be working - at least for me. Do you have any ideas on how to make it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `wantsLayer` to `true`. Standard window buttons are regular `NSButton`s with an `NSCell` inside them. To customize the and not have the original button block the view, you either need to remove the cell and use the layer or just create a custom one.

Note that when removing or setting your own button cell, its action selector will reset, so you need to keep sure that the buttons still do what you want them to.

Here's the code in Objective C, but it should be easy enough to translate into Swift:

```
NSButton *button = [self standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton];
button.wantsLayer = YES;
button.layer.backgroundColor = NSColor.greenColor.CGColor;

NSCell *cell = [[NSCell alloc] initTextCell:@"?"];
[button setCell:cell];
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This is totally what I was looking for. I've already found out that I would have to set wantsLayer to true but I didn't know that there is a NSCell inside those buttons.